# Hook in apache fineract, the request which was received in the local server doesn't contain the event response body

Tags: java, apache, mifos

I created hook in apache fineract- when new share product is created, the response of this event will send to a local server. 
The server actually received the event kind (SHAREPRODUCT CREATE) but **doesn't received the response body** which contains the new product id.

According to the Apache Fineract API Documentation(https://demo.openmf.org/api-docs/apiLive.htm) the hook should send also the response body. I don't know why it doesn't send it.

I attached here example of creating hook API, example of creating share product API, and the request which was received in the local server:.

Example of creating hook API:

```
    POST https://DomainName/api/v1/hooks?
    Content-Type: application/json
    Request Body:
    {
       "name": "Web",
       "isActive": true,
       "displayName": "Kremlin",
       "templateId": 1,
       "events": [
       {
         "actionName": "CREATE",
         "entityName": "SHAREPRODUCT"
       }],
       "config": {
          "Payload URL": "http://example.com/webhook",
          "Content Type": "json"
       }
    }
```

Example of creating share product API:

```
    POST https://Domain Name/api/v1/products/share?
    Content-Type: application/json
    Request Body:
    {
      "name": "Share Product",
      "shortName": "SP",
      "description": "Description",
      "currencyCode": "USD",
      "digitsAfterDecimal": 2,
      "inMultiplesOf": "1",
      "locale": "en",
      "totalShares": "1000",
      "sharesIssued": "1000",
      "unitPrice": "1",
      "minimumShares": "10",
      "nominalShares": "20",
      "maximumShares": "30",
      "minimumActivePeriodForDividends": "1",
      "minimumactiveperiodFrequencyType": 0,
      "lockinPeriodFrequency": "1",
      "lockinPeriodFrequencyType": 1,
      "allowDividendCalculationForInactiveClients": "true",
      "marketPricePeriods": [{
        "locale": "en",
        "dateFormat": "dd MMMM yyyy",
        "fromDate": "04 May 2016",
        "shareValue": "2"
      }],
      "chargesSelected": [{
        "id": 20
      }],
      "accountingRule": "1"
    }
```

Example Response:

```
    {
      "resourceId": 1
    }
```

The request which was received in the local server:

```
IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     destroyed: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: true,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  socket: 
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: 
      TCP {
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        _consumed: true },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Array],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Array],
        timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
        data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Array],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 1,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _bytesDispatched: 138,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '4:127.0.0.1:3000',
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 8 },
     _server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '4:127.0.0.1:3000',
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 8 },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: 
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idlePrev: 
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idleStart: 12293,
     _destroyed: false,
     parser: 
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     _httpMessage: 
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: 12,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nDate: Sun, 02 Sep 2018 08:48:31 GMT\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Length: 12\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
        _sent100: false,
        _expect_continue: false,
        statusCode: 200,
        statusMessage: 'OK',
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11,
     [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 13,
     [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 11 },
  connection: 
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: 
      TCP {
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        _consumed: true },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Array],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Array],
        timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
        data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Array],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 1,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _bytesDispatched: 138,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '4:127.0.0.1:3000',
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 8 },
     _server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '4:127.0.0.1:3000',
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 8 },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: 
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idlePrev: 
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idleStart: 12293,
     _destroyed: false,
     parser: 
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     _httpMessage: 
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: 12,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nDate: Sun, 02 Sep 2018 08:48:31 GMT\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Length: 12\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
        _sent100: false,
        _expect_continue: false,
        statusCode: 200,
        statusMessage: 'OK',
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11,
     [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 13,
     [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 11 },
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: false,
  headers: 
   { 'x-fineract-entity': 'SHAREPRODUCT',
     'x-fineract-action': 'CREATE',
     'fineract-platform-tenantid': 'default',
     'x-fineract-endpoint': 'https://mifos.cambium.co.il/fineract-provider/api/v1/',
     'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
     'content-length': '17',
     'user-agent': 'Java1.8.0_131',
     host: '127.0.0.1:3000',
     connection: 'Keep-Alive',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip' },
  rawHeaders: 
   [ 'X-Fineract-Entity',
     'SHAREPRODUCT',
     'X-Fineract-Action',
     'CREATE',
     'Fineract-Platform-TenantId',
     'default',
     'X-Fineract-Endpoint',
     'https://mifos.cambium.co.il/fineract-provider/api/v1/',
     'Content-Type',
     'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
     'Content-Length',
     '17',
     'User-Agent',
     'Java1.8.0_131',
     'Host',
     '127.0.0.1:3000',
     'Connection',
     'Keep-Alive',
     'Accept-Encoding',
     'gzip' ],
  trailers: {},
  rawTrailers: [],
  upgrade: false,
  url: '/',
  method: 'POST',
  statusCode: null,
  statusMessage: null,
  client: 
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: 
      TCP {
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        _consumed: true },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Array],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Array],
        timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
        data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Array],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 1,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _bytesDispatched: 138,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '4:127.0.0.1:3000',
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 8 },
     _server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '4:127.0.0.1:3000',
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 8 },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: 
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idlePrev: 
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idleStart: 12293,
     _destroyed: false,
     parser: 
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     _httpMessage: 
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: 12,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nDate: Sun, 02 Sep 2018 08:48:31 GMT\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Length: 12\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
        _sent100: false,
        _expect_continue: false,
        statusCode: 200,
        statusMessage: 'OK',
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11,
     [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 13,
     [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 11 },
  _consuming: false,
  _dumped: false }
```